# month wise reports by date

Tags: c#, sql

Is it possible to get this report format in sql. I tried various ways but no luck..any light on this would help me a lot.. I can get name, tickets from table but how can date wise report in sql. I dont want use any reports

```
NAME    1  2   3  4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12  13  14  15  16   17   18   19   20   21  22  23 24 (date)  
smrithi 10 20  34 45  55  55  66  77  33   44   55  56  44  66  77  88    55  22   33    11  44  99  77  88 (tickets)
XYZ     10 20  34 45  55  55  66  77  33   44   55  56  44  66  77  88    55  22   33    11  44  99  77  88
```

this is what I tried ..

```
SELECT *

FROM 
( SELECT CAST(DAY(t_date_time_issued) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS SaleDay,
CAST(MONTH(t_date_time_issued) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS SaleYear

FROM  dbo.tickets) as ts
PIVOT
( 
count(t_reference) 
FOR SaleDay IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],
[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],
[22],[23],[24] ) ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried.

Comment: What does your data look like in the database?  And what do you mean when you say you don't want to use any reports?  At a guess, you're looking at pivoting data, which is going to be vastly easier in a presentation tool.

Comment: i get this error 'Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'.'

Comment: I dont want to use any report viewer or third party tools

Comment: Could you put dbo.tickets structure and some example data?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    SELECT Name, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24] 
    FROM
    ( 
     SELECT Name, 
     CAST(DAY(t_date_time_issued) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS SaleDay,
     t_reference
     FROM  dbo.tickets) AS ts
    PIVOT
    (
    count(t_reference)
    FOR SaleDay IN ( [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23],[24] )
    ) AS pvt
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/052ff/5

Comment: I get this error incorrect syantax near pivot...`Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)      6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML      3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer      9.11.9600.16521
Microsoft .NET Framework      4.0.30319.18444
Operating System      6.1.7601`

Comment: Did you copy and paste my code and received that error? Check the sqlfiddle that I posted. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: your code is perfect on fiddle might be with my machine